# Meaning of "from his not being able to conceal from himself the ridiculous appearance that such a steed gave him, good horseman as he was"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> that at a time when everybody was
> a connoisseur in horseflesh, the appearance of the aforesaid
> pony at Meung[.....]produced
> an unfavorable feeling, which extended to his rider.
> And this feeling had been more painfully perceived by young d’Artagnan (the rider) [......]**from his not being able to conceal from himself the ridiculous appearance that such a steed gave him, good horseman as he was**. He had sighed deeply, therefore, when accepting the gift of the pony from M.d’Artagnan the elder.He was not ignorant that such a beast was worth at least twenty livres

The Three Musketeers by Alexandre Dumas

What did he mean by the bold part? I understand as [ the reason why he perceived this feeling so painfully is that he wasn't able to hide the " the ridiculous appearance" his horse's color give to him. Giving What a great a horseman he is, he should be able to].

Comment: D'Artagnan's bad feeling was perceived so painfully by him because he was not able to hide from himself the ridiculous appearance his horse's colour and manner of walking gave to him. This was because he was a good horseman (who knew about horses).

Comment: The " hide it from himself" or "conceal it from himself" are confusing. I don't if the point of hiding/concealing it is for him to not see it or for other to not see it.

Comment: D'Artagnan is a proud young man, and he would like to pretend to himself that he does not look ridiculous, but he is too good a horseman to succeed in that pretence. Have you never seen someone pretending that they do not know that they look ridiculous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horse gave D'Artagnan a ridiculous appearance in this sense. The horse had an odd **physical** appearance as D'Artagnan was aware because he was quite knowledgeable about horses. He further realized that most observers, not knowing the horse was a gift, would assume that he had had chosen to buy that odd horse, and would conclude therefore that D'Artagnan was simple minded and therefore **socially** ridiculous.

It is a remarkably convoluted sentence though that may be the fault of the translator rather than Dumas.

**EDIT**: Many thanks to Kate Bunting for locating the original. As she says, the French original is convoluted; the translator is not to blame for that. However, the word translated as “appearance” is perhaps not perfectly chosen. “Aspect” **might** better capture the flavor of the French original.

Comment: So " conceal it from himself" is for him not to see it?

Comment: "**not** being able to conceal it from himself" means he **DID** see it

Comment: The  original is pretty convoluted - _Et cette sensation avait été d'autant plus pénible au jeune d'Artagnan (...), qu'il ne se cachait pas le côte ridicule que lui donnait, si bon cavalier qu'il fût, une pareille monture_ - and the next sentence in the translation is part of the same one in the original!

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you sincerely for the original language. I have forgotten 80% of my French, but your comment inspired an edit in my post.

Comment: Luckily I realised that the passage must be near the beginning of the story! NB The word is _cavalier_, not _chevalier_ - D'Artagnan rode well but still looked silly on the odd horse.

Comment: I don't know if it's allowed. But I want to ask if [ he had sighed deeply] do you understand as he had sighed in amazed way for he thinks the horse is valuable or he had sighed in disappointed way because the horse looks ridiculous?

Comment: @Ali notice the "therefore" after "he sighed deeply": he knew the horse would give him a "ridiculous appearance"; *therefore* he sighed deeply.

Comment: @KateBunting NB noted. I’m not sure I knew the word “cavilier.” I have edited my answer. Thank you again.